# Replacing a string in a file with regex using shell

Tags: shell

hello i have a string in a file that looks like this:

```
VALUE "Git", "c464294e164b4vevre51651f14fe484a41aa03dace\0"
```

And i have a regex expression to match this git value :

```
"git",\s"(.*)"
```

I tried writing this command in shell. But it doesn't work:

```
sed -i.bak "s/\"git\",\s\"(.*)\"/ABC/gi" myfile.rc
```

The regex expression work if i try it here: https://regex101.com/r/VtXAFW/4

I don't know anything about shell i found out about sed on here

Can you help me fix why this sed command doesn't work pls?

## EDIT:

This works better: perl -p -i -e "s/\"git\",\s\"(.*)\"/x/gi" myfile.rc 
But it replaces the whole line and i only want to replace what the (.*)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 perl -pe 's/(?<=VALUE \"git\", \")(.*?)(?=\")/test/gi'
```

`(?<=something)` is lookahead

`(?=something)` is lookbehind

`?` in `.*?` makes match lazy/non-greedy

Comment: I just went for rewriting the whole line but with the variable i get in my script and it works, i don't know about your solution but thanks for helping out.